AeroThemePlasma does not launch and instead throws this error: Dependency '/usr/lib/qt/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/qmldir' is missing
I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and updated it to 22.04 and wanted to install a Windows 7 theme onto it, so I installed KDE Plasma and tried to run the AeroThemePlasma installer. I installed all of the dependencies, but it then failed giving me the error: Dependency '/usr/lib/qt/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/qmldir' is missing.
   KDE Plasma version: 5.24.7
   KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
   Qt Version: 5.15.3
   Kernel Version: 5.15.0-112-generic (64-bit)
   Graphics Platform: X11
   CPU: Intel Core i3-1115g4
   Integrated Graphics: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics

This may be a cause of Ubuntu being unsupported by the script, as stated in the installation instructions. However, I am getting the same error despite running on a fully-updated arch installation.
This error arises during the for-loop of line 148 in the installation script, specifically at the point where it runs command -v /usr/lib/qt/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/qmldir and gets a return code != 0. This means that qmldir is not an executable file OR simply doesn't exist (in which case it is not any sort of file).
In my case, it was that the file was not marked as executable, and I suspect your case is the same.
to fix this, you can just run the following
sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/qt/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/qmldir

and may have to do the same for the next dependency as well.
However, this does sort of raise the questions of why it is expected to be executable by the installation script to begin with...

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

i tried this command, but qmldir doesn't exist

According to the official Ubuntu file-list for the qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects package, the file is placed in a different location than on Arch...
I see two possible solutions for this:

change the code at line 149 of the install script
to:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/ \

this may cause issues if other files in the theme expect it to be in Arch's location
(to be cont.)




Other option:

link the directory at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/ to /usr/lib/qt/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/qmldir
I do not have an Ubuntu machine at the moment so I am not sure how much of that path already exists, but you can try:
to make sure the destination directory exists:
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/qt/qml
to link the directory:
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtGraphicalEffects /usr/lib/qt/qml/QtGraphicalEffects
to make sure all has gone well:
ls -l /usr/lib/qt/qml/

Note that there may be other issues, even if this on is fixed...

thank you! I will be sure to try this.

Did you ever end up getting things working? I tried setting this up on Plasma 5.27 (LTS) and ran into the same error on OpenSUSE Leap 15.6. I fixed it by simply removing the part of the script that threw it, and everything worked all right.
